# Exterior wall issue

Tags: exterior

The outside wall of my house seems to be rotting. Paint is coming off. I'm a newbie and don't know what exactly I should do. Climate here is long winter with at least 2 months of heavy snow and 2 more months of occasional snow. Hot summer is usually 1 month. Location: Toronto, Canada.

1. Would you please suggest what kind of contractors or companies I should get quotes from?
2. When getting quotes, what should I tell them over phnone, so they clearly understand the issue?

Please help. Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: @FreeMan Agreed. I removed that part from the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *good* handyman might be able & willing to take care of this. A general contractor would probably be overkill, but he might refer you to the carpentry crew he hires and they may be willing to take it on. Give a few people a call, and if they're not interested, ask for a recommendation of someone who might be. When you call the recommended person/company, be sure to tell them who sent you. That's part of how businesses build good reputations and good rapport.

Whoever you call, tell them you have rotting exterior window trim that needs to be replaced and repainted. From the angle of the picture, I'd guess it's on the second floor - you'd probably want to mention that. You may end up needing one person to fix the framing and another to do the painting, or you may hire someone who will take care of both parts, even if he subcontracts out the painting portion.